# Back to use the original \forall symbol

Tags: symbols, mtpro

I'm currently using Math Time Pro2, but considering the `\forall` and `\exists` is not suitable for my liking. How can I change back to the origin LaTeX `\forall` and `\exists` symbol?

One more question, is that is there a more-straight (double) (left) right arrow? (I mean, in the "head" of the arrow) The `\rightarrow`-like symbol all have curly embellishment, which I don't want.

Comment: By "origin[al] LaTeX", do you mean the Computer Modern versions of the symbols? (Computer Modern is available for PlainTeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and many other formats.)

Comment: You might be interested in [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764). However, you can also try to store the symbol before loading `mtpro2` (`\let\oldforall\forall \let\oldexists\exists \usepackage{mtpro2}`, for example).

Comment: @Mico. Yes! How can I redefine these symbol(only these particular symbol!) to the original one in Computer Modern?

Comment: @Werner. Great idea!  And after loading mtpro2, can I use the \oldforall to replace the \forall using in current session? I don't want to add three letters in every use.

Comment: @Eric: After loading `mtpro2`, does `\let\forall\oldforall \let\exists\oldexists` restore the symbols?

Comment: @Werner Almost surely not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load a math symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\let\mtproforall\forall % just for the comparison
\let\mtproexists\exists % just for the comparison

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\forall}{\mathord}{CMsymbols}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\exists}{\mathord}{CMsymbols}{"39}

\begin{document}

$\forall x\,\exists y$

$\mtproforall x\,\mtproexists y$

\end{document}
```

Look at the comparison and decide whether you really want the change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate!  By the way, how can I find a table of the code of symbols? Such like knowing \forall is "38, whereas \exists is "39

Comment: @Eric The default settings are in `fontmath.ltx` in you TeX tree.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to find the code for `\therefore`, but I can't find it in `fontmath.ltx`, where's it?

Comment: @Eric That's in `amssymb.sty`, as far as I remember.